# How can I create a JTextField that shows drop down menu, that drop menu would show the list of items from my Database?

Tags: java, netbeans, drop-down-menu

[How can I create a JTextField that shows drop down menu, that drop menu would show the list of items from my Database? ,Please see JTextField having Add and Clear Button in front of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFbw2.png)

Comment: please add what you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you need is **JComboBox**. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Comment: no, i need a search bar based on the items from my database.